# how to convert Base64 string into html in laravel 9

Tags: html, laravel, base64, laravel-9

Base64 string exist in Database, I am not able to convert base64 string into html in laravel 9.
Online base64 to html converter convert my base64 string easily .

here are my base64 string

"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"

I am trying for this issue

$file = "data:@file/html;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($base64String));

Comment: So, if you `base64_encode` it, you `base64_decode` it... I honlestly do not understand what you don't understand

Comment: Yes you are right ,Because i am beginner in laravel that 's why am put question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [base64_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to get the html back, as

```
$generatedHtml = base64_decode($base64String);
```